# view RGBA image

Tags: rgba

Can someone tell me how can I view an RGBA image? I just want a tool that I can display an RGBA image with!
I have written a code, which outputs only RGBA format. I just want to verify if my code worked, and just want to find a simple tool to view this image. 
I wasn't able to come across a software to be able to display a RGBA image. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

RGBA files only contain raw channel data. The binary data will not have enough information to display an image (ie. width,height,depth, &tc).

If you know the image dimensions of each `.rgba` file, you should be able to work with the data. Here's an example of viewing raw date in javascript.

```js
var fr       = new FileReader(),
    myWidth  = 200,
    myHeight = 200;

fr.onload = function(frEvent) {
 var canvasElement = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
     ctx           = canvasElement.getContext("2d"),
     blob          = ctx.createImageData(myWidth,myHeight),
     index         = 0;

 while(index < frEvent.target.result.length) 
   blob.data[index] = frEvent.target.result.charCodeAt(index++);

 ctx.putImageData(blob,0,0);  
}
```

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) will be able to display raw RGBA data. Assuming that each color sample is 8 bits.

```
display -size 200x200 -depth 8 mySimpleData.rgba
```